# How can I reset an image property to blank/null when changing another select in a dialog?

Tags: aem

I need to remove the image and hide its label in the dialog when a value is selected from another dropdown. I also want to remove the image from the component itself.

Currently, I am able to hide the image in the dialog, but the image is not removed and is passed to the JSP file. I am using `html5smartimage` as xtype.

This is the dialog.xml code:

```
<imagepath jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
           ddGroups="[media]"
           fieldDescription="Best display supported image for large (400 x 270px) 
                             and for small(260 x 193px)."
           fieldLabel="Thumbnail Image"                    
           fileReferenceParameter="./thumbnail"
           height="200"
           id="thumbnail"
           name="./bkgimage"
           rootPath=""
           width="150"
           xtype="html5smartimage"/>
```

Here's the JavaScript function:

```
function(comp) {
    var panel = comp.findParentByType("panel");
    var thumbnail = panel.getComponent("thumbnail");
    var dropdown = panel.findById("height");
    var width = panel.findById("width");
    var thumbnailAltText = panel.findById("thumbnailAltText");
    if (dropdown.getValue() == 'half-height') {
        thumbnail.hide();
        thumbnailAltText.hide();
        thumbnail.setValue(' ');
    } else {
        thumbnail.show();
        thumbnailAltText.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly add the code that you have tried till now.

Comment: I added the code .please check

Comment: Any help please..I am struck here not able to proceed